# Webpack / Angular not sending bootstrap to dist folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, webpack

I am trying to figure out how to get it all to work. The issue is that bootstrap isn't showing up in the dist version of the index page.

I am not 100% sure, but the .angular-cli.json is what I think is creating the webpack. This is the file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.31",
    "name": "webui"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the app this is the error I get in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:7:3482)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:7:12271)
    at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), <anonymous>:7:14333)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
    at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js (bootstrap.min.js?e084:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f1e578d…:54)
    at Object.3 (scripts.bundle.js:52)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f1e578d…:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap f1e578d…:25)
(anonymous) @ VM738:7
(anonymous) @ VM738:7
(anonymous) @ VM738:7
webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports @ addScript.js:9
../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js @ bootstrap.min.js?e084:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap f1e578d…:54
3 @ scripts.bundle.js:52
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap f1e578d…:54
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap f1e578d…:25
(anonymous) @ scripts.bundle.js:1
vendor.bundle.js:55378 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
```

Note, there isn't a tether file as it mentions, but that wouldn't be causing this problem? Not sure why bootstrap isn't being connected to the dist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried installing and including tether?

Install with: `npm i tether --save`

and include by adding to the `scripts` and `styles` sections of your angular-cli.json

```
  styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/css/tether.min.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ],
```

Comment: Where do I put those scripts?  Thanks

Comment: When you use the `npm i tether --save` command it should put the scripts in your `node_modules` folder. You then need to edit your `angular-cli.json` file as shown in my answer to include them whenever angular-cli builds your project.

Comment: Do you think when I add tether it will call the css too? Right now it doesn't want to call the css.

Comment: Yes, if you add the reference to `tether.min.css` in your `angular-cli.json` file (as shown in my answer) then it will be included in the bundle built by angular-cli